# Dwarven Mechanism stuck

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I'm trying to get the Elder Scroll via Septimus Signus. I've fought through the entire dwarven ruins and killed everything, but now the Dwarven Mechanism is stuck. I went through my inventory and I'm sure I have the ball to activate it, but when I click E to activate the mechanism, nothing happens. I'm not even getting an error message or anything.

I think it's a glitch; it's as if I hadn't even pressed the button. I tried closing and reopening my game, getting my character killed, and rebooting my computer, but nothing worked.

What else can I do? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you placed the Lexicon? the cube thing Septimus wants engraved and returned to him

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61032989

Comment: With these two tips in mind, head up the last slope, where you will find four buttons and a Lexicon Receptacle. Place the Blank Lexicon in the receptacle and watch the ceiling of the room open, shining light onto the container beneath. - Excerpt from http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elder_Knowledge